# Image Carousel Spfx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, image, react-webpart

Hi I am working on SPFx image carousel web-part using react responsive carousel.

I want that if user click on image on carousel it will show detail description of image in modal dialog on same page:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactCarouselProps> {
  return (
   <div className={styles.reactCarousel}> 
        <Carousel showThumbs={false} autoPlay={true} >    
          {this.state.items.map((imageList) => {    
            return (<div>    
              <img src={imageList.Image["Url"]} /> 
              <p className="legend">{imageList.Title}</p>   
            </div>)    
          })}    
        </Carousel>    
        <div>
         {this.state.items1.map((description) => {    
           return (<div> 

               <div  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: description.Body}} />
           </div>)    
         })}  
         </div> 
      </div>    
 ); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onClickItem` attribute of Carousel to right your own function to show the details of clicked image from carousel. you can add it on carousel like:

```
<Carousel showThumbs={false} onClickItem={_onClickItem} autoPlay={true} >    
    {this.state.items.map((imageList) => {    
        return (<div>    
                    <img src={imageList.Image["Url"]} /> 
                    <p className="legend">{imageList.Title}</p>   
                </div>)    
        })
    }    
</Carousel> 

function _onClickItem() {
    console.log('onClickItem', arguments);
}
```

Check the implementation of there at: [react-responsive-carousel](https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel/blob/master/src/main.js).

NPM Package Reference: [React Responsive Carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel).

And to show the modal pop-up you can use any one of the modal popups in React JS:

[React Modals](https://reactjsexample.com/tag/modals/).

Personally I liked the [Modal-React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/).

Comment: Actually this is a very broad question. Even though I have given some hints and references to look upon. Have you tried this? Is it working for you?

Comment: i have not tried it but it give me idea from where to start i will let you know the output,i thought of using modal dialog of office farbic for pop up .

Comment: Sure, let me know if there is any issues.

Comment: This is just to follow up on this question. Have you tried this?

Comment: yes I am working on this and will update soon

Comment: i tried the same and abe to call pop up fabri modal on click event passing parameter

Comment: Great... You are rocking with SPFx development... I am glad it worked for you :)